# What does “@keyframe doesn't cascade" mean?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I was reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), it says

> @keyframes rules don't cascade, so animations never derive keyframes
>   from more than one rule set.

what does "cascade" mean here? English is not my native language and there is no more detailed explanation so I don't understand what it means. Can anyone explain this with an example?

Comment: this might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

Comment: It doesn't mean anything different from what "cascade" means elsewhere in CSS. You do realize that's what the C in CSS stands for, right? Strange that you should have this question only now.

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aunza1wb/). The `color-change` animation has two definitions with distinct frame percentage selectors inside both but you'd see how just the latest `@keyframe` rule wins and they are not combined.

Comment: `div{display:block}`, `div{display:none !important}`. For these declarations, I can say the latter css declaration is "winning over/overriding/cascading" the former one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**An example of CSS cascading: -**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 200px; /* Sets width */
}

h1 {
    font-size: 14px; /* Overrides 12px rule above */
    height: 200px; /* Sets height */
}
```

In the above example the **h1** elements font size is first set to *12px* in the first rule and then overridden to be *14px* by the second rule. The width is set in the first rule and the height is set in the second rule. This is cascading:  multiple rules determine the final styles applied, with priority given to properties in the rules descending order.

**An example of Keyframes cascading**

```
/* WILL NOT CASCADE */

@keyframes exampleAnimation {
    0% { top: 0; left: 0; margin: 10px; }
    100% { top: 100px; margin: 20px; }
}

@keyframes exampleAnimation {
    0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
    100% { top: 0; left: 100px; }
}
```

**The above example will not cascade.** That is to say, *only the last rule declaration is used for the animation*. The animation will move the animating element *100px to the left*, it will ignore the *top* and *margin* animations set in the previous rule declaration.